# Concerning rds in MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

Why is \$r_{o1}\$ connected to the ground in the second diagram which is the small signal equivalent (formal solution, hence most likely correct)?:
[image]
[image]

Comment: There is some confusion regarding the names of the resistors. On the title you say \$r_{ds}\$, in the text you say \$r_{o1}\$ and then in the lower figure we can see only \$r_{os}\$. Besides that, are you sure this \$r_{os}\$ refers to the MOSFETs? It seems as if it is the substitution of the current sources.

Comment: @nickagian You're right, it's the output resistance of the current sources :-)

Comment: @nickagian But what's the difference? I notice that the book states that all these resistances are equal to \$V_A/I_D\$, which is the standard rds of a MOSFET.

Comment: In the 2nd schematic I do not see the feedback resistor R2 being properly incorporated into the schematic. The 2nd schematic seems to have no feedback at all. So I don't see how it be the full small signal version of the 1st schematic.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie It includes instead the input and output feedback resistances, namely R1||R2 and R1+R2

Comment: Sure but the overall gain will be less due to the feedback. I do not see that happening in the 2nd circuit. The 2nd circuit will have a higher gain from Vs to Vo than the 1st circuit. Also for output impedance, the loopgain matters as it will lower output impedance by the loopgain. At least that's what I know from 20 years experience with circuits like this. But if anyone knows better, I'm willing to learn ;-)

Comment: My guess is fig 2 is the open loop gain model and closed loop is simply R2/R1

Comment: Possibly they're assuming the current sources are MOSFET current mirrors? But it seems odd to assume the p-MOS one (on the drain of Q1) has the same characteristics as the n-MOS ones.